# Best way of using web services on iOS?

Tags: iphone, xml, web-services, authentication, ios

I'd like to build an iOS app which lets you log in to a web service.

After that, the app would (when the user chooses) send the login name/pass, together with the requested variable(s), over https. For instance after requesting 'news-update', it would receive the requested info in XML format... something like:

```
<news-update>
  <title>Kim Jong-un Promoted</title>
  <story>North Korean leader Kim Jong-il's youngest son, Kim Jong-un, has been appointed a general, amid rumours he is being anointed as successor...</story>
</news-update>
```

What APIs and techniques should I use for these kind of tasks? I don't want to use any UIWebViews, but instead use standard UI elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Ole said, except instead use `ASIHTTPRequest` to send and receive data over the network.

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLConnection` to send and receive data over the network and `NSXMLParser` to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

RestKit provides excellent support for quick and easy RESTful requests: http://restkit.org/